# How to display gcov html result in jenkins

Tags: hyperlink, jenkins, gcov

I want to show the gcov `index.html` result file in Jenkins. I tried with *sidebar link plugin*. But I don't know how to configure the path like:
`/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/platform_linux_test_report/code_coverage/121127/index.html`

I got error as below:

```
Status Code: 404
Exception:
Stacktrace:

(none)
```

Anyone knows how to use it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong plugin. You probably want to use the [HTML Publisher Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) instead.  It allows you to add any arbitrary HTML page (site) that is created in your build.